# About FFMPEG Install and Used

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

My client need me to dev a ios video player and suppor flv,avi format video . i search some info on google and know about "FFMPEG".

i know what is it and know i can use it to dev the video player . but i have a question , how to install and  use it ?? have any doc and demo ? i have no idea how to use it on xcode .

i have already see ffmpeg website and that havent say how to build it on ios or macox , any one can help me ???

And i know about MobileVLC, and i try to install on my xcode project . but is doesnt work for me , the error is `MediaLibraryKit/MLFile.h was not found` actually i dont konw MobileVLC can play flv and avi or not ?? can anyone give me some idea or send me some link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avi is a container format , what actual codecs are you trying to play. We've done this before and we certainly can help. check our github here.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

Also check out http://www.xiph.org/ for some alternative codecs and players

MobileVLC was part of the VLC app that apple pulled , I don't know if its a good idea to use that. Have you looked at the forum at www.videolan.org which is the home of vlc

Comment: Thanks Guys..i download the git project and try to build it, but it doesnt work . and i search some info about vlc. but still havent idea to use and install it

Comment: That git has 9 ffmpeg projects which did you build

Comment: The name is "iFrameExtractor"

Comment: IframeExtractor from my git, that should build a lot of people have. what is the build error you are getting. Your better off using one of the other projects like webstreamX_flv_demo for non rtsp streams.

Comment: Thanks guy, actuelly i need to play flv format video online , i want to inset some mov player like VLCMobile etc.. and i try the webstreamX_flv_demo that has a little problem for my project .

Comment: What little problem. Please explain